# Checking if the uploaded file is csv

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this method called import file which I am trying to upload a CSV. I want to check that the uploaded file in csv format. I did do the 
   **<%= file_field_tag :upload_entries, accept:'.csv' %>** but that didn't work so I am trying to write this begin and and rescue block in the controller 
and not able to rescue the error when some other format of the file is uploaded . I get this error "
**ArgumentError in SheetEntriesController#import
"** when I upload .jpg or .xls file Can someone help me with it?

```
require "csv"
  class SheetEntriesInvalid < Exception
end

class SheetEntriesController < EntryController

  unloadable

  def import
    if (params[:upload_entries]).present?
      begin
        SheetEntry.import(params[:upload_entries].path)
        redirect_to root_url, notice: "Updated Succesfully"
      rescue 
        redirect_to root_url, notice: "Invalid CSV file format."
      end
    end
  else
    redirect_to root_url, error: "No File Chosen"
  end 
  end
end
```

Comment: Your code won’t even be parsed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to handle file uploads. In general using exceptions to control flow is considered bad practice. With paperclip you can enforce a validation for the file's content-type up front in your Model rather than relying on `SheetEntry.import()` to raise an exception.

```
class SheetEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_filed :csv
  validates_attachment :csv, content_type: { content_type: ['text/csv','text/plain']} # 'csv' files may have text/plain as a content-type.
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I would also like to how to do it using the begin and rescue statement.

Comment: I would argue that this approach is more thorough than trying to rescue the exception in your controller. `rescue` without a specific exception catches all `StandardError`s, not necessarily just the the one you are intending it to catch. In any case, in order to know how to capture the exception correctly, we would need to know how `SheetEntry.import` is defined

Comment: Also there is a lengthy discussion here if you are interested in knowing why using exceptions to control flow is bad practice: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why or https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/107727/279615

Answer (score 1):

You can check the file mine type

```
class SheetEntriesController < EntryController
  def create
    puts MIME::Types.type_for(file_path).first.content_type # "text/csv"
    if MIME::Types.type_for(file_path).first.content_type == 'text/csv'
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

I hope that this helps